# Replace unicode character

Tags: php, unicode, replace

I am trying to replace a certain character in a string with another.  They are quite obscure latin characters.  I want to replace character (hex) 259 with 4d9, so I tried this:

```
str_replace("\x02\x59","\x04\xd9",$string);
```

This didn't work.  How do I go about this?

**EDIT: Additional information.

Thanks bobince, that has done the trick.  Although, I want to replace the uppercase schwa also and it is not working for some reason.  I calculated U+018F (Ə) as UTF-8 0xC68F and this is to be replaced with U+04D8 (0xD398):

```
$string = str_replace("\xC9\x99", "\xD3\x99", $_POST['string_with_schwa']); //lc 259->4d9
$string = str_replace( "\xC6\8F", "\xD3\x98" , $string); //uc 18f->4d8
```

I am copying the 'Ə' into a textbox and posting it.  The first `str_replace` works fine on the lowercase, but does not detect the uppercase in the second `str_replace`, strange.  It remains as U+018F.  Guess I could run the string through `strtolower` but this should work though.

Answer (score 5):

U+0259 Latin Small Letter Schwa is only encoded as the byte sequence 0x02,0x59 in the UTF-16BE encoding. It is very unlikely you will be working with byte strings in the UTF-16BE encoding as it's not an ASCII-compatible encoding and almost no-one uses it.

The encoding you want to be working with (the only ASCII-superset encoding to support both Latin Schwa and Cyrillic Schwa, as it supports all Unicode characters) is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Ensure your input *is* in UTF-8 format (if it is coming from form data, serve the page containing the form as UTF-8). Then, in UTF-8, the character U+0259 is represented using the byte sequence 0xC9,0x99.

```
str_replace("\xC9\x99", "\xD3\x99", $string);
```

If you make sure to save your `.php` file as UTF-8-no-BOM in the text editor, you can skip the escaping and just directly say:

```
str_replace('ə', 'ә', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible suggestions.  Firstly, remember that you need to assign the new value to $string, i.e.:

```
$string = str_replace("\x02\x59","\x04\xd9",$string);
```

Secondly, verify that your byte stream occurs in the $string.  I mention this because your hex string begins with a low-byte, so you'll need to make sure your $string is not UTF8 encoded.