# How to replace accents like \u0219 in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, replace, diacritics

I have a PHP script which is used by an Ajax function to pass some input variables in a MySQL database. But a string like "Camping Dragoske, DN73C, Burluși" is stored in the MySQL database like "Camping Dragoske, DN73C, BurluÈ™i, RomÃ¢nia" and is captured by the ajax.php file like "Camping Dragoske, DN73C, Burlu\u0219i, Rom\u00e2nia".

My HTML charset encoding is UTF-8, and the MySQL table is set to `utf8_general_ci` and the field is set to `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: I would try to do something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959626/replace-unicode-character?rq=1

Comment: Are you using jQuery to make the Ajax call? Otherwise you might need to convert from the charset Javascript uses internally to UTF-8 yourself.

Comment: Whatever you are using to see how it is "stored in the database" is not properly displaying UTF-8, by the looks of it. Anyway, the actual bytes are important for resolving this issue; but apparently, ș is stored as the bytes 0xC8 0x99 just like it should be.

Comment: @tripleee I'm using the phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Wolfgang Stengel. Yes, I use jquery to make the ajax call.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replace special characters with the ones they're based on in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1890854/), [How do I remove accents from characters in a PHP string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1017599/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the encoding of the MySQL connection. For a bug free utf8 environment, you need to set the page, the database and the mysql connection to UTF-8.

Try this function:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

or better use mysqli:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.set-charset.php